# Append all values of a SQL result into an array

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I want to create an array based on the results of my `SELECT` query.

The below code works somewhat -- it only adds the last row to the array. I tried declaring the array beforehand and then using `array_push` but that function doesn't allow me to assign a key, just a value.

```
    $sql = "SELECT setKey,setValue FROM tblsettings WHERE setApp = '".$data->app."' AND setIP = '".gethostbyname(trim(gethostname()))."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if(!$result) die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0){
        echo "null";
        exit;
    }

    while($datAssArr = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $datArr = array($datAssArr["setKey"] => $datAssArr["setValue"]);
    }

    print_r($datArr);
```

Comment: Don't use mysql_* it's deprecated. Use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$datArr = array($datAssArr["setKey"] => $datAssArr["setValue"]);
```

Try:

```
$datArr[] = array($datAssArr["setKey"] => $datAssArr["setValue"]);
// ----^
```

Also, don't use the `mysql_*` functions. They're deprecated. Try [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: Thank you, with your help I ended up using `$datArr[$datAssArr["setKey"]] = $datAssArr["setValue"];`

Comment: I've switched to PDO since this discussion, but am having issues... see new question here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627423/inserting-multiple-rows-with-a-single-query-using-pdo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19627423/inserting-multiple-rows-with-a-single-query-using-pdo)