# Inserting multiple rows with a single query using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, pdo

I have switched to PDO and am having trouble building and executing a SQL query that will insert multiple rows with just one execute.

Contents of `$data` after json_decode:

```
Array (
    [action] => load
    [app] => CA
    [street_type] => AVE
    [place_type] => --
    [state] => AL
)
```

Code:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$query = "REPLACE INTO tblsettings(setApp, setIP, setKey, setValue)VALUES";
$qPart = array_fill(0, count($data), "(?, ?, ?, ?)");
$query .= implode(",", $qPart);
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);

    foreach($data as $key => $val){
        $query = "REPLACE INTO tblsettings(setApp, setIP, setKey, setValue)VALUES";
        $qPart = array_fill(0, count($data), "(?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $query .= implode(",", $qPart);
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);

        $i = 1;
        if(!is_array($val)){
            $stmt->bindParam($i++, $data->app);
            $stmt->bindParam($i++, gethostbyname(trim(gethostname())));
            $stmt->bindParam($i++, $key);
            $stmt->bindParam($i++, $val);
        }

        if ($stmt->execute()){
            echo "Success";
        }else{
            echo $stmt->errorCode();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @JonB. Quick question. Any specific reason you're using `REPLACE` as opposed to `INSERT` ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- because the rows may already exist, therefore I'm updating if so, inserting if not.

Comment: @JonB. Ok, I understand. And I assume that you have a `PRIMARY KEY` or `UNIQUE` index ?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes `UNIQUE` is set on `setApp`, `setIP`, and `setKey`

Comment: @JonB. Your data is coming in from an array, am I right? If so, then why the `!` in [`!is_array`](http://us1.php.net/is_array)? This tells PHP that, if it is `not` an array, then execute. Therefore it will only use the first entry and dump/skip the rest of the data in the array.

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's checking if `$val` is an array, which it shouldn't be during the `foreach($data as $key => $val)`

Comment: if it shouldn't be - then it shouldn't be such condition in the code.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Doesn't hurt to check

Comment: It DOES hurt. The very direct and related way. I kinda like such questions where couple participants cannot debug 5 lines of code in a couple of hours. However, remote virtual debugging is hard to perform, I have to admit.

Comment: @YourCommonSense You can't say _why_ it hurts? I'm trying to learn something new.

Comment: Well, it was quite obvious to me: you are depriving your very self from the helpful error message. At the moment, In case of wrong data you'll silently end up with wrong number of bound variables. While having this useless condition taken out you will be informed of such an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess `$i = 1;` should be inside the `for` loop and outside the `if` loop, because for every for loop it will be incremented by 4, which we dont want we, want to start from 1 and reach 4 and exit for every `for` loop

```
 $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
 $query = "REPLACE INTO tblsettings(setApp, setIP, setKey, setValue)VALUES";
 $qPart = array_fill(0, count($data), "(?, ?, ?, ?)");
 $query .= implode(",", $qPart);
 $stmt = $db->prepare($query);

 foreach($data as $key => $val){
   $i = 1; //for every for loop reset it to 1
   if(!is_array($val)) {
      $stmt->bindParam($i++, $data->app); //here it will be 1
      $stmt->bindParam($i++, gethostbyname(trim(gethostname())));  //here it will be 2
      $stmt->bindParam($i++, $key);  //here it will be 3
      $stmt->bindParam($i++, $val);  //here it will be 4
   }
  }

  if ($stmt->execute()){
        echo "Success";
   }else{
        echo $stmt->errorCode();
   }
```

Comment: edited my answer, you need to execute the insert statement in for loop as well

Comment: er, now it's not inserting multiple rows with a single query.  it's inserting multiple rows with one query each.  :)

Comment: Probably due to the `foreach` loop. Try and close it after `$stmt = $db->prepare($query);`

Comment: exactly, what does $data contain? $data->app, $key, $val

Comment: `$data` is just an array of values that were passed from a form.

Comment: is my answer relevant?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Doing so will only insert one row. @plain jane that updated code will insert multiple rows, but not by using only one `execute`.

Comment: @plainjane `execute()` is within the `foreach` loop therefore causing multiple executions. I'm trying to accomplish just 1 execution for performance.

Comment: just check the output of `echo $query;` and let us know

Comment: `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));` dont you think this should be `$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);`

Comment: @plainjane adding `true` to json_decode results in object errors. Results of your newest edit is that `$query` only contains `REPLACE INTO tblsettings(setApp, setIP, setKey, setValue)VALUES`

Comment: $query should be `REPLACE INTO tblsettings(setApp, setIP, setKey, setValue)VALUES (?,?,?,?),(?,?,?,?)` this piece `(?,?,?,?)` this should be repeated n times provided n is the count of array $data

Comment: i meant output of `$query .= implode(",", $qPart);`

Comment: @plainjane `$query` contains `REPLACE INTO tblsettings(setApp, setIP, setKey, setValue)VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?),(?, ?, ?, ?),(?, ?, ?, ?),(?, ?, ?, ?),(?, ?, ?, ?)` but I also received 5 errors that say `Attempt to modify property of non-object` on this line: `$stmt->bindParam($i++, $data->app);`

Comment: what is the output of `echo "<pre>"; print_r($data);`

Comment: i want contents of $data array, add this to your question

Comment: @plainjane I've added the contents of `$data` to my original post.

Comment: $data->app you need $data['app'] here right? what is `setApp` column with regards to $data array value

Comment: @plainjane No... `$data->app` is just fine. The problem is that I don't want to use multiple calls to `$stmt->execute()`. `setApp` columns will contain `$data->app`'s value which in this case is `CA`

Comment: i removed it and used it outside for loop pls check

Comment: @plainjane I've got to rest, work in the morning. I will continue tomorrow.

Comment: @plainjane I spoke to a PHP guru and was informed to use `mysqli` instead of `PDO` for performance reasons. Thanks for your time and input. I indeed learned some from you as well as the other contributors.